# How should this sed command be rewritten to avoid an unterminated 's' command error?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I'm slowly following along with a Linux certification textbook just to bolster my skills a little. Text stream processing is the current topic, and the command I'm working with out of the book uses sed to replace text in a dummy file. The dummy file looks like:

[test]

```
Jane     F     14     Algebra    90
George   M     13     French     88
...
```

and the command (including piping the dummy file as input) from the book looks like:

```
cat test | sed '/Jane/s/14/16'
```

This command should find lines in the test file that contain the string Jane, and then replace the string 14 in those lines with the string 16. However, it returns an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
```

There have been a few typos in this book so far, maybe 4 over the span of 400 pages. So this could be just another typo, but I'm assuming that I missed something. Does anyone see the issue?

[Image of the text from the textbook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeouN.png)

Note, the figure in the book runs this command without the single quotes (so simply 'sed /Jane/s/14/16') but running it this way returns with the same error.

Comment: It is a typo. The command should be `s/14/16/` with a trailing `/`

Comment: Thanks! I tried so many combinations of moving things around, but never noticed that the figure in the book had the trailing slash.